# Would it be possible to create a site on climate change?

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

As climate change is a hot topic in the scientific community nowadays, with broader and broader subtopics, I thought it could be interesting to introduce a Stack Exchange on Climate Change. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to create a new site since there is one already covering this particular topic. It's [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) and they currently have [404 questions about climate change](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change). If you want to ask questions about how to change your lifestyle to prevent (further) climate change, there's a site about [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/).

Normally you'd create a new site proposal on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) but this one is going to be closed as duplicate of an existing site.

Comment: I disagree. I think the topic does include areas that are not obviously suitable for a site about earth science. One example would be the psychology of the effect  that there are people not understanding it, and the sociology of why this varies significantly by geographical region, even in similar cultures. I recently did ask a question on climate change there and it did not even occur to me that it was part of the topic. So I took care to concentrate on the physical aspects. I recently proposed the site [Climate Change](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123397/climate-change)

Comment: I also disagree, the attention of many people focused on climate change makes it a more relevant matter than its "parent category" earth science matter. I believe climate change deserves its own stack community.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of topic this StackExchange would cover that others StackExchange dont cover yet?

## Earth Science

> Questions about changes of the climate system, including questions about global warming.

[`climate-change`](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change)

## Skeptics

> Climate change is a significant and lasting change in the statistical distribution of weather patterns. In public discourse, often used as a shorthand for the effects of anthropogenic global warming.

[`climate-change`](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change)

Comment: Climate change is no more just a scientifica matter. It is a topic that is involving human life and choices. I would agree on dedicating to climate change a specific stack community so that it would be the right place to post questions about how to reduce  lifestile choices induces emissions amount.

Comment: A specific website targetting climate change would be way more interesting than topics on Earth Science or Skeptics. Climate change is nowadays a bigger topic than both these communities and the name of these communities will not draw people trying to get information about climate change.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely to me that you would be able to because:

- Climate change is on topic at [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) so you’d have to make the case that you’re not duplicating that part of the site
- You need a specific website of people interested in the topic. [“If you do not yet have a community organized, ready and eager to build your site, please do not submit this proposal.”](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=arts)